# Why does $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin (xy)}{x} \to y $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{\sin (xy)}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$. How should you define $f(0,y)$ for $y\in \mathbb{R}$ so as to make $f$ a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

So in order for a function to be continuous the limit of the function approaching the point has to equal the value of the function at the point. In this case the trouble point is $(0,\,y)$. Now i looked at some other posts and took the suggestion of using L'Hopital's rule. Using it I get the right solution, but I don't understand why doing L'Hopital does provide the right solution? If i am in a multivariate environment, how am i allowed to use something like L'Hopital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From calculus of one variable it is known that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$

Then, if $y\neq 0$ let $t=xy$, $x=t/y$, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (xy)}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{y}{1}\frac{\sin (xy)}{xy}\right]\\
&=y\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\\
&=y(1)\\
&=y
\end{align*}

Then, in order to get $f$ be continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is needed $f(0,y)=y$

Answer (score 2):

In a multivariate environment, you can't guarantee that the answer you get using L'Hopital will make your function continuous. However, you can guarantee that *if* your function *can* be made continuous, L'Hopital's rule will give you the right answer.

In your case, you want $f(x,y)$ to be continuous on $\mathbf{R}^2$. That means, in particular, if you hold $y$ constant and vary $x$, then $f(x,y)$ must be continuous as a function of $x$ for all possible $y$. To make this condition hold, you use L'Hopital's rule to fill in the discontinuity, viewing $f(x,y)$ as a function of just one variable, $x$.

This does NOT guarantee your function is continuous everywhere. Once you get your values for $f(0,y)$, you have to go back and PROVE these values make your function continuous. However, if it's possible for your function to be continuous, these will necessarily be the correct values.

Comment: Ok. So building on the fact that $ f(0,y) = y$. Would i prove that my function is continuous at this value by this:  $$ \frac{|sin(xy)|}{|x|} \leq \frac {|xy|} {x} = y $$

Comment: @dc3rd You need to show that $|\frac{\sin(\delta x(y+\delta y))}{\delta x}-f(0,y)|<\epsilon$. I don't think that inequality helps, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @dc3rd I would try expanding $\sin()$ using sum identities.

Comment: I am not sure why you have all those deltas. Isn't the continuity condition: $|\frac {sin (xy)}{x} - f(0,y)| < \epsilon $, which is$|\frac {sin (xy)}{x} - y| < \epsilon $?

Comment: @dc3rd No, you need to allow both $x$ and $y$ to change at the same time to prove continuity in $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence a $\delta x$ and a $\delta y$. You want to show that as $(x',y')$ get arbitrarily close to $(0,y)$, the functions are the same. I just set $x-0=\delta x$, $y'-y=\delta y$. Makes sense?

Comment: @dc3rd If you only let $x$ change, you already know the function is continuous in that sense, because using L'Hopital's rule gave you that for free. It's when both $x$ and $y$ change that continuity is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: Yea. Makes sense now. Thanks, but now thinking on it, it really isn't a simple manipulation to show continuity in this case...

Comment: @dc3rd It's not super-straightforward, but I think if you use a sum trig identity things will come together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fundamental limit for $\sin$ instead: $$\frac{\sin(xy)}{x} = y\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} y \cdot 1 = y.$$The point is that $y$ is *fixed* here.